# How to debug a SQL natural join resulting in additional rows?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling to debug a SQL join. I could brute-force it, but I am sure there is tooling for this.

I have 5 tables of that should "just" left join into each other on the common column names.

Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u -- user_id's are unique
JOIN user_groups ug ON ug.user_id = u.user_id 
JOIN group_importance gi ON gi.group_id = ug.group_id
```

However, I'm finding about 10% too many rows in the final output (which I expected to be of the same length as `users`)

I implemented the above using

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
NATURAL JOIN user_groups
NATURAL JOIN group_importance
```

But I can't easily tell the error.

Note that I've checked for duplicate joining keys, and for spurious column overlaps.

Note that I'm using Snowflake/DBT.

Comment: Start watching differences in result output  of these two query.

Comment: I would say that a user could sit in multiple user_groups? So sounds logical that this query returns more records that the number of users?

Comment: user_groups indicates it is kind of bridge table for implementing many-to-many  relationship `N:M`, so it is possible that after join there is more row(for instance a user belonging to two groups.

Comment: I solved the issue; it was more that I had to check table by table and see where the row explosion happened. Just wanted to see if there was any better tooling than experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

Either your `user_groups` table contains more than one entry for some users, or your `group_importance` table contains more than one entry for some groups, or both.

JOIN gives back all possible pairs of rows from the tables being joined. That is, it gives back all pairs of rows that match the explicit ON condition, or the implicit one generated by NATURAL JOIN. It's no surprise that `FROM a NATURAL JOIN b` sometimes yields more rows than are in `a`.

You could find the offending rows like this.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), user_id
  FROM user_groups
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `natural joins` make debugging a pain. I would run the query with explicit joins and add a `qualify` at the bottom to just look at the dupes. You can partition by additional columns to look at dupes for different groupings

```
qualify count(*) over (partition by u.user_id) > 1
```

Comment: Good to know it's not just me on the Natural joins point :P